# Power Service seems linked to continuous cycling of "Windows Explorer Has Stopped Working" post start up of Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-services

Ok, this one really has me flummoxed, so I thought I would turn to the world that the StackExchange network and see if I could find some help.

I am currently running a Windows 7 Ultimate N 64 Bit install on a i7-2600K core with 16Gb of RAM. The machine has been running smoothly for sometime until this AM when I turned the machine on to discover that it was continually looping through a series of "Windows Explorer Has Stopped Working" and then attempting to restart Windows Explorer only to stop again. Over and over, non stop.

I determined the following after a few hours of going through typical procedures:

Those procedures were:
Safe Boot
Malware and Virus Scans (note: the system frequently updates, runs antivirus software, and sandboxes all browser instances when online)
Checked All Third Party Software
Checked All Services (Non Windows)
Checked All Windows Services

When I checked the services and did a series of binary searches to run down the offending service or process I locked in on the Power Service.

With everything else turned on an running, and the Power Service disabled, the machine boots and runs as normal with one exception. The Audio device no longer functions.

Enable the Service and return to the same cycling behavior.

I attempted to start the audio device, and met with no success, the device would not start. There was a dependency that seemed unable to start (Windows Audio Endpoint Builder Service) because a dependency was unreachable (RPC Server).

I am sort of stuck at this point, as I can't untangle what web of connections exist at this low level to isolate and repair the issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I should also add, I did some hardware testing (memory, audio, etc.) using a live cd boot of Ubuntu. Just for completeness sake.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling/updating your motherboard and/or audio adapter drivers?